# Why can you not select Scopes for Registered App on developer.uber.com?

Tags: uber-api

I have created an app on developer.uber.com and am using oauth, user access token to retrieve data from https://api.uber.com/v1.2/me. I am getting following error

Error below

{
"code": "unauthorized",
"message": "This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: profile, request.delegate, eats.pos_provisioning, profile.internal_uuid"
}

Per API documentation, I tried to follow these steps but ability to select Scopes in developer dashboard does not exist:

1. Select an existing application (or create a new one)
2. Go to the Auth tab
3. **Select the scopes that you want to test with**
4. In the “Test with a Personal Access Token” module, click “Generate a new token”. The token generated will only be displayed once, and the token will be generated with the selected scopes from your Uber rider account that is signed into the dashboard.

Additional documentation indicates that privilege scopes are available for development but seems this may be incorrect:

"Some scopes, such as the request scope, are privileged scopes. By default, privileged scopes are limited to your development team. To use them in production, request Full Access. **The good news is you currently have access to these scopes when authorizing your own account or those of the developer accounts you list in your application dashboard (Limited Access). This allows you to start building an app immediately."**

Here are steps I took to test:

1. User Authorize step requires scope which I did include in browser:

   https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>&scopes=profile
2. Received a single-use authorization code from step 1 and used this code to get an access token using:

   ```
   curl -F 'client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>' \  
         -F 'client_id=<CLIENT_ID>' \  
         -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \  
         -F 'redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>' \  
         -F 'code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE_FROM_STEP_1>' \  
         https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token
   ```
3. Used access token from Step 2 as Authorization Bearer token to make api call https://api.uber.com/v1.2/me

   curl -H "Authorization: Bearer {TOKEN}" 
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US' 
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
   "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/me"

Error below

{
"code": "unauthorized",
"message": "This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: profile, request.delegate, eats.pos_provisioning, profile.internal_uuid"
}

Has anyone identified why scopes cannot be selected or cannot call Uber API as owner/developer?

Thanks.

RA

Comment: hey @user19265377, Did you manage to request scopes on the Uber API?
I'm also trying to start using the API, but I can't for the same reason.

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Hi, did you fix this? Did you have to sign a legal agreement?